# How do I retrieve a subset of fields using Spring's MongoTemplate and Query classes?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I want to be able to execute the following console command to return all rows with only a subset of fields populated but using Spring's [`MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) class:

**Console Command**

```javascript
db.person.find(null,{name:1})
```

**MongoTemplate**

```java
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(...), Person.class)
```

Info on projection (subset) queries can be found [in the MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: You're telling it to find `name:1`. Surely that would mean you want `1` to be returned.

Comment: There appears to be a fields() method on the Query object: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-query.query

Comment: Looks like you have to use @Query annotation in order to take advantage of this feature. Hopefully I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
Query q = new Query();
q.fields().include("name");
mongoTemplate.find(q, Person.class);
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a lifesaver. I wish the spring docs would be better though - when i clicked here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Field.html all the methods doc were blank.

Comment: @JamesC It works but it returns object. What if I want to get just a field like    String myField = mongoTemplate.find(query, "myCollection"). Is that possible?

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince late to the party but sorry, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection(COLLECTION).find(null, new BasicDBObject(FIELD, "1"))
```

Comment: what would the second argument to the method `find` look like if we had to project multiple fields?

Comment: @asgs you can construct the BasicDBObject using a Map, or you could parse a json projection and cast it as a DBObject :  ```DBObject projection = (DBObject) JSON.parse("{'_class':1, 'field1':1, 'field2':1}");```

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to populate the standard domain object with just the subset of fields, using `d.fields().include()` as described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429167/1108305) is the way to go.  However, often time I find having the full object is undesirable (having a partially-populated could easily mislead future developers reading the code), and I'd rather have an object with just the subset of the fields I'm retrieving.  In this case, creating and retrieving a projection object with just the subset of fields works well.

**Projection class**

```java
@Document("person") // Must be the same collection name used by Person
public class PersonNameOnly {
  private String name;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

**`MongoTemplate` query**

```java
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(...), PersonNameOnly.class);
```

---

If you want to use the same projection object for multiple types, you can omit the `@Document` declaration with the collection name from the projection object, and specify the collection name in the `MongoTemplate` query.

**Projection class**

```java
public class NameOnly {
  private String name;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

**`MongoTemplate` query**

```java
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(...), NameOnly.class, "person");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mongoTemplate.findDistinct(String field, Class<?> entityClass, Class<T> resultClass);
```